# Checkbox event change calling function and pushing it a object

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to do a checkbox change so when it is clicked it pushes a value into my object. (yes i know push is a array method). So i wondering what i can do to make this work.. i have used a onclick event because jquery was not working for me.. here is my code:

My object is called Contact() and holds 'address1' in there. Contect() is a object NOT  function. i just need to know how to push a object value into it?

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="no-custom" id="CheckBox" onclick="CheckBox()" > <span class="BlackColor">Use my email.</span></label>
```

function CheckBox() {

```
Contact().push({Key: 'address1', Value: 'hello@hotmail.com' });

                        }
```

I would rather do my jquery way which is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#CheckBox').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {                        
        Contact().push({Key: 'address1', Value: 'hello@hotmail.com' });
        }

    });
});
```

But this was not firing on the checkbox being clicked.. can anyone guide me to know how to push a object value and sort my checkbox event.

Thanks

Comment: It is a object holds value of address1.

Comment: Try removing the `()` from `Contact()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize a contact:

```
var c = new Contact();
```

then in your code:

```
c.address1 = 'hello@hotmail.com';
```

Comment: it already declared all i want to do is update a value in that object?

Comment: c.address1 = 'hello@hotmail.com';

Answer (score 0):

It seems to fire the event as show in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dzaLj0pv/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#checkBox').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {                        
        alert("This is checked");
        }
    });
});
```